# Laptop: upgraded DDR3L 1,35V RAM but Windows can't boot with the new one

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

[Picture of the 3 RAM memories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqS6S.jpg)

The laptop is a [Toshiba Tecra A11-110](http://www.toshiba.pt/discontinued-products/tecra-a11-110/) with an intel i5 processor.

I replaced the first RAM with the second one. The Windows begins to boot but ms later shuts down and the computer restarts again.
Maybe the reason was that the second one was 1,5V.
An analysis on Kingston website says [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQeh1.jpg) are the compatible ones, 1,35V.
So, I bought the third one you see in the image. But the same thing happens: windows can't boot, it begins but quickly dies.

What could it be?
Thank you.

Comment: It most likely is the frequency.  You have purchased significantly faster memory than the Samsung module.

Comment: The original one is this one https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/dram/module/M471B5673FH0-CF8/  (1066) but Crucial and Kingston say that these ones are compatible: https://eu.crucial.com/eur/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Toshiba/tecra-a11-110#MEMORYFilters

Comment: That list is perfect, especially if you, mix and match the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing ram voltages is not a good choice as in some cases it won't work, depending on motherboard. You will have to either undervolt the 1.5v to 1.35v or overvolt the 1.35v to 1.5v. You can do that in the BIOS in some motherboards, or maybe you can get another 1.35v memory instead.

Comment: I am just using the new one.

Comment: That's strange. Does the boot really begins? Does the Windows really starts to load?

Comment: Yes, it does. The windows loading animation begins but instantly the whole thing restarts.

Comment: Have you tried the memory in another machine to make sure it works? Maybe it's a hardware problem.

You can also insert a live cd and try to boot another OS to make sure the problem isn't with windows.